# Long polling with EmberJS / Ember-Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, long-polling, polling

I have setup a very basic first application where I can add and remove names from a list, which are then added/removed from a database using a RESTful API, using Ember-Data with the default REST Adapter.

I'd like to implement some form of polling/long-polling so my interface remains up-to-date.

So for example, lets say I open my 'list' in two tabs, delete a few names in one tab - I'd like for the changes to then (eventually) show up in the other tab.

How can this be done easily with Ember?

Comment: what you mentioned with `say I open my list in two tabs...` would actually not working out of the box, you can read more about this in this open issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is really a job for WebSockets, which would allow you to push changes to your models from the server to the Ember app whenever they happen.  This type of approach can easily take care of keeping thing in sync between tabs.  I would recommend checking out [Socket.io](http://socket.io), which has a great client-side JS library and many server side libraries.  By default it will try to use WebSockets, which are better than long-polling, but will degrade to long-polling if it needs to.  This might force you to change a bunch of your application set-up, but I would consider this the "right" way to go.